# php - preg_replace - adding a protocol to href and src elements

Tags: php

Is it possible to add a protocol to urls (href & src) which don't contain the protocols ?

For example, I would like to replace this URL:

```
<a href="/page/image.png" target="_blank">TEXT</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="http://my-webpage.com/page/image.png" target="_blank">TEXT</a>
```

But important is two things:

- if original URL in href/src is starting from slash "/", the protocol with domain should be add without slash on the end but when original URL isn't starting from slash - the protocol with domain should be add with slash,
- if original URL is starting from "../" or "./" etc. - that should be remove and then, the protocol with domain should be add with slash.

Is it possible to do it in one regex ?

Thanks.

EDIT:

There is my code:

```
$url = 'http://my-page.com/';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('"charset=([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)"si', $html, $charset);
$charset = strlen($charset[1]) > 3 ? $charset[1] : 'UTF-8';
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', $charset);

preg_match_all('"href=\"(.*?)\""si', $html, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] AS $key => $value)
{
    if ( preg_match("/^(http|https):/", $value) )
    {
        continue;
    }

    $html = str_replace($value, $url.$value, $html);
}

preg_match_all('"src=\"(.*?)\""si', $html, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] AS $key => $value)
{
    if ( preg_match("/^(http|https):/", $value) )
    {
        continue;
    }

    $html = str_replace($value, $url.$value, $html);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think just `<a href="//my-webpage.com/page/image.png" target="_blank">TEXT</a>` will do the trick in many cases

Comment: Ever considered something more precise, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: I would like to print a code from another website on my website so I have to add full URLs if I want see all images from original website etc.

Comment: @Machavity I would like to do it using regex. I wouldn;t like to use DOMDocument, because DOMDocument  will be print an errors if in HTML code will some mistakes, for example when in code will be adding <b> tag without close. DOMDocument isn't good solution for me.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, and I believe it should be possible. It would be helpful if you had some code that you have tried as a starting point.

Comment: I added my code but It doesn't use a regex because I don't know how to create this regex...

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex in a sed or other recipe:

```
sed 's/href="/href="http://site.domain/g'
```